# Outlook 2007 GAL Phone List

Tags: active-directory, exchange

I just spent a lot of time populating Phone Numbers and Fax Numbers in our GAL/Active Directory.

The goal of which was to replace our static *.xlsx file that we use as a corporate phone directory.

I know I can see the GAL by clicking on the To... button, and I can see more specific info for a particular user, by adding them as a recipient and double-clicking their name in the To: field.

Is there any way (inside Outlook) to have a laundry-list view of all users and phone/fax/mobile/address similar to the phone list view for contacts?

Are there any other tools that might provide this functionality.  I've used a GAL web interface before, but that cost $ and as I recall was challenging to manage.

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238773 - largely on point to this.  You can't really view it directly, but you can export it into contracts.